# angularjs - HTTPpromise does not execute when JSONP is returned

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jsonp

I am trying to get a stock quote from yahoo's api and I am using angular's $http.jsonp method. The goal is when the result comes back, to have the app go to the this route: '/stocks/show_stock'. I am trying to do it in two ways and neither works
1) I put the statement:

```
window.location = '/stocks/show_stock'
```

in the callback function that wraps the JSONP response
2) I put the statement:

```
$location.path '/stocks/show_stock'
```

in the HTTPpromise callback. (see the comments in the code)

Here is my code (in coffescript):

```
#THIS IS THE CALLBACK FUNCTION THAT I SEND WITH THE JSONP REQUEST  
window.stock_quote_callback = (data)->
  console.log data #THIS WORKS AND I CAN SEE THE DATA RETURNED FROM YAHOO
  window.stock_quote_result = data.results
  alert 'I am in the callback'
  #THE STATEMENT BELOW DOES NOT WORK EVEN THOUGH I CAN SEE THE ALERT ABOVE
  window.location = '/stocks/show_stock'

angular.module('Services').service 'StockSupplier', ($http)->
  get_stock = (symbol)->
    q = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes 
        where symbol in ("'+symbol+'")
        &format=json&
        diagnostics=true&
        env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&
        callback=stock_quote_callback'
    url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='+q 
    $http.jsonp(url).then (data)->
      #THE CODE BELOW NEVER EXECUTES EVEN THOUGH RESULT IS RETURNED
      alert 'This should pop up when result returns'
      $location.path'/stocks/show_stock'

  {
    get_stock: (symbol)-> get_stock(symbol)
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have not added callback=JSON_CALLBACK to the url, the url should be http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q='+q

Comment: it is there. the 6th line of the 'q' string. As I mentioned that is not the problem I do get the callback to fire but window.location = '/stocks/show_stock' inside that callback does not work. That is why I tried to use the 'then' function of httpPromise but that didn't work either

Comment: Thanks Ajay now I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't write coffeescript, so I translated it to javascript. You forgot to inject the `$location` service, other than that I just replaced the `callback=stock_quote_callback` to `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` and created a plunker that runs just fine: http://run.plnkr.co/hCAdohIJIr9Odn3m/ (source: http://plnkr.co/edit/a7C6k0QVoXnaTyImSUkb?p=preview).

```js
angular.module('Services').service('StockSupplier', function($http,$location) {
  var get_stock;
  get_stock = function(symbol) {
    var q, url;
    q = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("' + symbol + '")&'+
        'format=json&'+
        'diagnostics=true&'+
        'env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&'+
        'callback=JSON_CALLBACK ';
    url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + q;
    return $http.jsonp(url).then(function(data) {
      alert('This should pop up when result returns');
      $location.path( '/stocks/show_stock' );
    });
  };
  return {
    get_stock: function(symbol) {
      return get_stock(symbol);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch jo! Reading the angular documentation I thought that 'JSON_CALLBACK' was a placeholder for the name of the function you want executed when the response returned, and not that I have to literally put 'JSON_CALLBACK' as the name of the function. That solved it.